# How to pass multi word string as a variable used in url in php

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, audio

I am making a voice dictionary.
Here is my code.Its working fine with no errors but just a slight problem. The line towards the end is where i have the problem.

http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=$z";?>" type="audio/mp3" />

$x and $y variables contain a single word ..so they are easily converted to speech without the need of encoding and my code works fine for them. But when i write $y which stores meaning , the speech output is not there as meaning contains multi word string which has to be encoded first ( But i dont know how to encode it).

Plz tell me what changes i have to do in order to convert the meaning part also from text to speech.

I tried with 
http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=.urencode($y)"; ?>" type="audio/mp3" />

but it didnt work. PLZ HELP

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Word meanings</title>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "radhika");
mysql_select_db("dictionary");
if(isset($_POST['Submit1']))
{

 $req=$_REQUEST['word'];
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dict WHERE word='$req'";
 $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
 {
        $x=$row["word"];
    $y=$row["meaning"];
    $z=$row["synonym"];
    echo "<b>Word</b>: " . $x ."<br/>" ;
    echo "<b>Meaning</b>: " . $y ."<br/>" ;
    echo "<b>Synonym</b>: " . $z ."<br/>" ;
  }
 }
 mysql_close();
 ?>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="lastry.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="word" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['word'])?$_POST['word']:''?>"x-webkit-speech/>
<Input Type ="Submit" Name ="Submit1" Value ="submit"> 
</form>
<?php  if($_POST)
{
?>

<audio controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="<?php echo "http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=$z";?>" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest trying the URLencode function initially and let us know the results:

e.g.

```
urlencode($z)
```

in place of any variables that could potentially have spaces / special characters within them.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?q=<?php echo urlencode($y);?>&type="audio/mp3" />
```

Comment: yes this worked.But text to speech is working for some words only . For eg.if the meaning is "hello world" , its being converted speech but if the meaning is "disorderly crowd" then its not working